Combine paths to one output in Splunk
I have an issue with paths in my Splunk search. I am searching through JSON data where certains paths can have capitals, but also for a certain flow don't have capitals. The fields are exactly the same, but the capitals of the fieldnames are the difference. How can I combine the paths (because as far as I know the paths are treated as two different paths by Splunk) to get one output and combine them in the count?
index="x" 
| spath MessageTemplate | search MessageTemplate="Input Message: {Body}"
| spath input="Properties.Body"
| spath input="Properties.Body" path="voormelden{}.colloData{}.voormeldBronCd.code" output=VoormeldBronCode
| spath input="Properties.Body" path="voormelden{}.ColloData{}.VoormeldBronCd.Code"
output=VoormeldBronCode
| stats count by VoormeldBronCode

As you can see the paths for the body can be with capitals or with camelcase and I want to combine those in one output, so the count takes both of the versions (obviously this example doesn't work).

I think you may need to normalize the data in one of two ways: change the field(s) of interest to always have the same name; or change all of MessageTemplate to lower case.
index="x" 
| spath MessageTemplate | search MessageTemplate="Input Message: {Body}"
| eval MessageTemplate=lower(MessageTemplate)
| spath input="Properties.Body"
| spath input="Properties.Body" path="voormelden{}.colloData{}.voormeldBronCd.code" output=VoormeldBronCode
| stats count by VoormeldBronCode

or
index="x" 
| spath MessageTemplate | search MessageTemplate="Input Message: {Body}"
| rex mode=sed field=MessageTemplate "s/\\\"code\\\"/\\\"Code\\\"/g"
| spath input="Properties.Body"
| spath input="Properties.Body" path="voormelden{}.ColloData{}.VoormeldBronCd.Code"
output=VoormeldBronCode
| stats count by VoormeldBronCode


Try this run-anywhere SPL, making use of coalesce:
| makeresults count=10
```create mockdata```
| streamstats count
| eval
test=if(count%2=0,"test",null()),
Test=if(count%2=1,"testi",null())
| makejson * output=data
| table data
| eval data=replace(data,", \"[tT]est\": \"\"","")
```end mock-data```
```extract both fields```
| spath input=data path=Test output=Test
| spath input=data path=test output=test
```use coalesce to normalize```
| eval tTest=coalesce(test,Test)
| stats count by tTest

